# Problema de instalación de numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Intento utilizar `sum` en un programa *Python* pero cuando ejecuto el siguiente script me dice que no tengo *NumPy*.

```
:~$ ./testPostreSQLPython.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testPostreSQLPython.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Entonces hago la siguiente instalación :

```
:~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

... pero el error no se soluciona:

```
:~$ ./testPostreSQLPython.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testPostreSQLPython.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Pienso que [ésta respuesta](https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects/issues/67) de @workpioupiou puede ser correcta. Parece que es a causa del *VirtualEnv* (una herramienta para crear entornos *Python* aislados) con elementos *Python* preinstalados.

#### Actualización

He intentado hacer lo que me propone @FZNB, pero sigue con el mismo problema:

```
:~$ conda update conda
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/antoine/anaconda2:
#
conda                     4.3.18                   py27_0  
:~$ conda update numpy
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/antoine/anaconda2:
#
numpy                     1.12.1                   py27_0  
:~$ conda install numpy
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/antoine/anaconda2:
#
numpy                     1.12.1                   py27_0
```

**Actualización 22/5**

```
:~$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.5m-config /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3.5-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.5 /usr/share/python /home/antoine/anaconda2/bin/python /home/antoine/anaconda2/bin/python2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Y

```
:~$ conda create --name pythontests python=2 numpy
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/pythontests:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    mkl:        2017.0.1-0   
    numpy:      1.12.1-py27_0
    openssl:    1.0.2k-2     
    pip:        9.0.1-py27_1 
    python:     2.7.13-0     
    readline:   6.2-2        
    setuptools: 27.2.0-py27_0
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0     
    tk:         8.5.18-0     
    wheel:      0.29.0-py27_0
    zlib:       1.2.8-3      

Proceed ([y]/n)? 

openssl-1.0.2k 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:02   1.60 MB/s
readline-6.2-2 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.65 MB/s
tk-8.5.18-0.ta 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:01   1.74 MB/s
zlib-1.2.8-3.t 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.77 MB/s
setuptools-27. 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.58 MB/s
wheel-0.29.0-p 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.91 MB/s
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate pythontests
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > source deactivate pythontests
#

:~$ ./testPostreSQLPython.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testPostreSQLPython.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
(pythontests) antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:~$ conda install numpy
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/pythontests:
#
numpy                     1.12.1                   py27_0  
(pythontests) antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:~$ ./testPostreSQLPython.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testPostreSQLPython.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Comment: Revisa la versión de python que estas utilizando si es ```python 3``` debes instalaro con ```pip3```

Comment: @juliansalas Cuando hizo `:~$ python -V` tengo :
`Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`

Comment: Falta conocer el [shebang](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) que usa tu script, que es donde está el problema. ¿Qué pasa si fuerzas el intérprete, algo así: `python testPostreSQLPython.py`?

Comment: No se si entendi si lo que me dice fue para conocer : `#!/usr/bin/python`.
Si fuerzo el intérprete todo funciona como se esperaba

Comment: estuve googleando un poco y encontre esto, trata de instalar numpy desde los fuentes a ver como te va.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/install.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- la opción **menos recomendada** :

según [la respuesta de David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237522/no-module-named-numpy),

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpys
```

Pero es peligroso porque algunos módulos pueden contener código malicioso o ejecutarse en el sistema y como raíz. Incluso si resuelve el problema, puede crear una brecha de seguridad

- La opción **más recomendada**

es usar un entorno virtual :

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate
python -m pip install[module][samples]
```

- una otra opcion :

instalar en local usando `--user`

```
python -m pip install --user
```

Comment: Esta solución tiene un problema: trabajar sobre la instalación de python del sistema operativo no es recomendable.Cualquier problema de configuración o de instalación puede hacer dejar de funcionar el resto de aplicaciones. Mejor crear un virtualenv o utilizar conda para evitarlo ;)

Comment: -1 por lo que dice @FZNB.

Comment: @astrojuanlu, Hasta la semana pasada, realmente no estaba usando entornos virtuales porque no entendía. Ahora entendí, me convertí y cambié mi respuesta en consecuencia :D

Comment: Actualizado :))

Answer (score 4):

Es probable que el Python que estés utilizando sea el del sistema operativo (Linux o Mac) y no el que instalaste con Anaconda. En una terminal nueva:

`whereis python`

Te dirá que instalación estás utilizando. Si no aparece Anaconda ahí significa que hubo algún problema durante la [instalación](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-linux).

Como parece que `conda` sí que te funciona, una cosa que puedes hacer es crear un entorno para trabajar con la versión de python que necesites. Para ello, [siguiendo este tutorial](https://conda.io/docs/test-drive.html#managing-environments):

```
conda create --name pythontests python=2 numpy
```

Esto creará un entorno llamado pythontests con la versión 2.7.x y numpy listo para usar. Este entorno viene a ser una versión independiente de Python que para utilizarla debes primero activar con:

```
source activate pythontests
```

Una vez dentro con el entorno activo puedes instalar el resto de paquetes que quieras con `conda install nombre_paquete`.

Para desactivarlo puedes cerrar la terminal o escribir `source deactivate`.

Por otro lado, Ananconda es mejor tenerlo actualizarlo. Desde una nueva ventana de comandos, con:

```
conda update conda
conda update numpy
```

El gestor de paquetes que viene con Anaconda (llamado conda) es, con varias mejoras, similar al virtualenv que mencionas.

Para instalar un módulo o librería es mejor primero probar con:

```
conda install numpy
```

Si quieres instalar algo via pip (en lugar de conda):

```
conda install pip
```

y asegurarte si ya lo tenías, que sea la última versión:

```
conda update pip
```

Si creas un entorno nuevo, tienes que volver a instalar en ese entorno NumPy. Te recomiendo que lo hagas siempre primero con conda o [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.github.io/).

Dale un vistazo a [este vídeo en español](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLuwGhvWJzE) y a la [documentación rápida de conda](https://conda.io/docs/using/cheatsheet.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta ! Sin embargo no sé porque pero no funciona la actualización... Sigue con el mismo error

Comment: Si tienes varias instalaciones de Python puede dar problemas. Veo que utilizas Linux, así que lo que creo está pasando es que inicias el Python del sistema, no el de Anaconda. Escribe en una ventana de comandos nueva `python` y dinos que te aparece arriba del todo cuando inicia.

Comment: O mejor, escribe `where python` en la terminal y dinos qué te aparece. Si no aparece Anaconda deberás de añadirlo al PATH. Mira el [punto 7](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-linux) del enlace.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta con una alternativa, aunque todo apunta a que tuviste problemas durante la instalación y configuración del PATH.

Comment: Si pienso que tiene razón, sin embargo tengo un problema con el `where` : 

Cuando hizo 

    `:~$ where pyhton
    No command 'where' found, did you mean:
     Command 'gwhere' from package 'gwhere' (universe)
    where: command not found
    :~$ man where
    No manual entry for where`

Comment: @Marine1, prueba con `which python`

Comment: en realidad el comando es : `whereis python`

Answer (score 1):

Yo voy a proponer una aproximación diferente al problema. Se basa en el gestor de versión de Python [**pyenv**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) que te permite instalar en tu equipo diferentes versiones de Python sin que entren en conflicto.

Para esta respuesta, asumo que estas usando el sistema operativo Ubuntu Linux.

#### 1. Instalación de dependencias de Ubuntu

Lo primero que hay que hacer es instalar ciertas dependencias del sistema operativo para *asegurar* el correcto funcionamiento del proyecto.

Primero actualizamos las fuentes de paquetes y los paquetes que sean necesarios.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

A continuación instalamos los siguientes paquetes.

```
sudo apt install git python-pip make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev
```

Estas dependencias se instalan por si es necesario compilar alguna versión de Python o alguna extensión. Se incluye el metapaquete `build-essential` y las versiones de desarrollo de las librerías SSL, BZ2, ReadLine y SQLite3.

Puede ocurrir que ya tengas instalado alguno de estos paquetes, pero no hay problema con ello, verás un mensaje como este:

```
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1).
libbz2-dev is already the newest version (1.0.6-8).
libreadline-dev is already the newest version (6.3-8ubuntu2).
libsqlite3-dev is already the newest version (3.11.0-1ubuntu1).
make is already the newest version (4.1-6).
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

#### 2. Instalación de PyEnv

La forma más simple de instalar [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) es usar el [**instalador**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer), porque en una terminal, solo tienes que escribir lo siguiente:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

Al terminar la instalación verás estas tres líneas en tu archivo `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Si usas ZSH, entonces asegúrate que esas líenas estén presentes en `.zshrc`.

#### 3. Activación de PyEnv

Para activarlo, puedes cerrar tu terminal y abrir una nueva o escribir en la terminal que estás usando

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

> #### Nota
>
> En este ejemplo estoy usando BaSH, pero si utilizas otro intérprete, simplemente haz el cambio correspondiente.

#### 4. Instalación de versión

PyEnv tiene muchas opciones que puedes ver escribiendo `pyenv` en la consola, por brevedad en este ejemplo, solo explicaré las que usemos.

Para conocer que versiones de Python tenemos disponibles, usaremos este comando, que mostrará **las 309 versiones** de Python disponibles.

```
$ pyenv install --list
```

Si deseas ver solo las 40 versiones de anaconda, podemos usar un filtro

```
$ pyenv install --list | grep anaconda
```

Veo en tu pregunta que estás usando python 2.7, así que voy a elegir la versión **`anaconda2-4.3.1`**, que espero que sea la correcta (por algo dice anaconda**2**, ¿no?).

Para instalar, vuelvo a usar el comando `install` más la versión seleccionada.

```
$ pyenv install anaconda2-4.3.1
```

La versión que estoy instalando en este ejemplo, tiene 460+ megas, por lo que dependiendo de tu conexión puede tardar bastante.

```
Downloading Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh...
-> https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
Installing Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64...
Installed Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64 to /home/javier/.pyenv/versions/anaconda2-4.3.1
```

#### 5. Activando la versión instalada

Antes de poder usar cualquier versión instalada **es muy importante** hacer un *rehash* de las versiones. Con esto se activan los *shims* (el conjunto de variables que atrapan todas las llamadas a Python y las redirigen al entorno activo).

```
$ pyenv rehash
```

Ahora vamos a revisar las versiones instaladas.

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/javier/.pyenv/version)
  3.6.1
  3.6.1/envs/blog
  anaconda2-4.3.1
  blog
```

Ya podemos ver nuestra versión lista para usar.

#### 6. Crear el entorno virtual

El entorno virtual se crea de la siguiente manera:

- `pyenv` - que es el gestor de versiones
- `virtualenv` - que es el comando para entornos virtuales
- `anaconda2-4.3.1` - que es la versión que usaremos para este entorno virtual
- `marine` -  que es el nombre para este entorno virtual

> ```
>  $ pyenv virtualenv anaconda2-4.3.1 marine
>    Fetching package metadata .........
>    Solving package specifications: .
>    // Se instalan muchos paquetes, pero los omito por brevedad...
> ```

Cada versión de Python tiene requisitos diferentes, pero PyEnv se encarga de gestionarlas de forma automática.

#### 7. Activando el entorno virtual

Una de las mejores características de PyEnv es que los entornos se activan automáticamente al cambiar de directorio.

Es muy fácil. Solo escribe este comando **en el directorio de tu proyecto**:

```
~/projects/marine $ pyenv local marine
```

Esto crea el archivo `.python-version` que contiene la versión o el entorno que PyEnv activará al cambiar a ese directorio.

Además agrega un indicador del entorno activado en el *prompt*.

```
(marine) javier@javier-VirtualBox ~/projects/marine $
```

El entorno está listo para usarse.

#### 8. Usando el nuevo entorno

El entorno es local, no necesitamos permisos para instalar paquetes, por lo que instalar algo basta usar `pip`.

```
~/projects/marine $ pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.12.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (16.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.5MB 49kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.1
```

Y todo funciona como se espera:

```
~/projects/marine $ python
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.12.1'
```

#### 9. Cómo usar el entorno en scripts

Debido a que ahora las llamadas a Python son atrapadas por los *shims* es importante conocer dónde está realmente instalado el ejecutable de Python:

```
$ which python
/home/javier/.pyenv/shims/python
```

Hay un comando especial para conocer la ubicación exacta del ejecutable

```
$ pyenv which python
/home/javier/.pyenv/versions/marine/bin/python
```

Esta es la ruta que deberías usar en un script para asegurar que usas el entorno adecuado.

Borrar un entorno es muy fácil, solo elimina el directorio donde está instalado en `~/.pyenv/versions/` y has un `rehash`.

Si quieres usar esta versión para otro entorno, no tienes que volver a instalarla, solo crear el nuevo entorno.

Usa frecuentemente `pyenv version`, te dará información de las versiones y entornos instalados **y como activas el entorno actual**, lo que te dará un control muy preciso de tus entornos.

```
~/projects/marine $ pyenv versions
  system
  3.6.1
  3.6.1/envs/blog
  anaconda2-4.3.1
  anaconda2-4.3.1/envs/marine
  blog
* marine (set by /home/javier/projects/marine/.python-version)
```

> ### Notas finales
>
> - Creo que debí usar `conda` para instalar Numpy
> - Yo pensaba que Anaconda ya traía instalada una versión de Numpy, pero parece que no.
> - ¿Faltó algo? Mi entorno `marine` está instalado, puedo hacer algunas pruebas si hace falta.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías probar instalar numpy con `pip3` (instala paquetes para usarse con python 3.X) en vez de con `pip` (python version 2.x).  Anaconda usa ambas versiones (la 3.X y la 2.X de python) pero por lo que veo te instalaste la que usa 2.X.

el comando en distribuciones basadas en debian es:
`sudo pip3 install numpy`

Comment: hmmm... gracias por su repuesta pero me diece por una parte `The directory '/home/antoine/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`, lo mismo para `'/home/antoine/.cache/pip'` y por otra parte : `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.`